# RPostgreSQL: datetime convert as date

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I'm using  the `RPostgreSQL` package to load data from a PostgreSQL data base.

The problem is that a datetime column (POSIXct)  is automatically convert into a date.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="abc",host="def ",port=1234,user="ghi",password="jkl" )
```

Instead of using this:

```
df = dbGetQuery(con, "
    SELECT customer_id, dttm_utc
    FROM  schema.table;")
```

I have to use that:

```
df = dbGetQuery(con, "
     SELECT customer_id, to_char(dttm_utc, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as dttm_utc,
     FROM  schema.table;")
```

If I don't I loose the time and only recover dates.

I noticed this probem doesn't occur if I only want the first 1000 rows. It appears almost all the time when there is more than 300 000 rows.

**How can I fix this ?**

Comment: any updates on this?  I think i'm running into a similar issue

Comment: I did the test and it doesn't happens to me. In my case, ddtm_utc is of type `timestamp(6) with time zone`  in the database... object in R is `str(df) 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ customer_id: int  0 1 22 21 24 27 28
 $ dttm_utc   : POSIXct, format: "2020-03-02 21:00:00" "2021-12-29 21:00:00" ...`

Comment: did it with 300K rows also `str(df)
'data.frame': 300000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ customer_id: num  7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16 68 ...
 $ dttm_utc   : POSIXct, format: "2020-05-31 20:00:04" "2020-05-31 20:00:05" ...
> `